# In XAMPP numbers act different than real servers?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, precision, biginteger

I noticed an error happening only with XAMPP.

I tried with 4 other live hosting accounts (including AWS, hostgator and 2 others), they all act the same upon numbers but not XAMPP.
Here is what happens when running the same **echo** on real servers and XAMPP:

```
/* ALL SERVERS */
$testid = 5039307356925138;
echo (int)$testid;// 5039307356925138
echo $testid;// 5039307356925138

/* XAMPP AT WINDOWS 10 LOCALHOST*/
$testid = 5039307356925138;
echo (int)$testid;// 753691858
echo $testid;// 5.03930735692514E+15
```

What does this mean and why!?

After working for hours in the issue, checking every forum post,

I increased precision in php.ini and restarted apache:

precision=20 (note that all live servers are only 12!)

Now it is:

```
/* XAMPP */
$testid = 5039307356925138;
echo (int)$testid;// 753691858
echo $testid;// 5039307356925138
```

As you may already guess it is still not a solution and scripts do not run properly because XAMPP treats 5039307356925138 as 753691858 ?!?

Furthermore, increasing precision too much caused problems like 3.250000000001% or something where other numbers are used.

I tried re-installing XAMPP with new version and tried this on another computer but all are the same.

For those of you using XAMPP in windows localhost, do you see the same problem?

What might be the cause? how to fix it????

Comment: What versions of PHP are the server and XAMPP using?

Comment: Is XAMPP 32bit, while the other 64bit perhaps? When working with large number, if you exceed 2^32 on a 32bit system, you will experience what's called "overflow", which is likely what you're seeing.

Comment: XAMPP: 3.2.2 XAMPP PHP Version 5.6.14 where live servers different versions but all of them run OK. I tried previous version of XAMPP and on different computer but every time again, I see the problem above. AND yes XAMPP is 32 bit and windows is 64 bit. But XAMPP don't have 64 bit version?

Comment: For Windows, I don't think there's XAMPP 64 bit, but there is for Linux and iOS (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Although, since PHP is loosely typed, you could use it as a string instead of an actual integer, `"10" == 10`. This can be helpful when working with very large numbers.

Comment: WAMP has 64-bit for Windows as far as I know. XAMPP only has 32-bit.

Comment: @Sondre Correct, but if OP is using PHP5.6 then on windows PHP not fully 64bit until PHP7 specifically integers are still 32bit until PHP7

Comment: Yes it temporary fixes when converted to string with "5039307356925138" BUT I'm posting it to API and it only accept integer so I get an error response. AND I can't use wamp because I need SSL (https) on localhost and only XAMPP supports it.

Comment: Have you tried casting to float instead?

Comment: @Sondre with precision set to 12 like live servers, XAMPP returns echo (float)$testid;// 5.03930735693E+15 So the scientific notation is still a problem when posting to API. I tried increasing precision and using (float) as you suggested, it works but increasing precision too much causes unnecessary precision like 3.20000000001% on other parts of the script... (on live servers it is just 3.2%, I'm surprised... )

Comment: @tarik Yeah, setting the precision that high isn't really an option then. Not quite sure what the solution can be then.

Comment: OK after a day of work trying to solve the issue, I decided install WAMP 64 bit as you suggested with my 64 bit Windows 10 operating system. But I still face the "overflow" issue!?!? I did have to increase precision in php.ini to 16 MORE, echo (int)$testid;// 753691858 Now I have all 64 bit wamp + 64 bit computer why is the overflow issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using XAMPP, it only has 32bit for Windows. This in turn means that number may not exceed the range of [−2 147 483 648, 2 147 483 647]. On Linux and iOS I believe there's 64bit version for XAMPP.

So its very likely that your hosts use a 64 bit version, which would allow usage of much higer numbers as integers. What you're seeing is *overflowing*, the limit is reached and you "start again" from the bottom range.

Since PHP is loosely typed, a string and integer can be compared with the same value, eg

```
"10" == 10 // true
"11" == 10 // false
"10" === 10 // false because of strict comparison
```

So it might be a solution to work with strings instead of integers (because there's no limitation in the length of a string).

---

From the [release announcement](http://php.net/releases/7_0_0.php) of PHP7, its announced that from PHP7 onwards, there will be consistent support for 64bit. So if the OS running it, and the engine is 64bit with PHP7 or higher, you will have full support for 64bit (which in turn allows you to use higher integer values).

Comment: Aye, that's true. Should probably edit in a note about the version too, I'll do that when I get back to my desk.

Comment: My script works well on every live real servers so I don't really want to modify it only to work with XAMPP. Furthermore, I'm posting the ID to API and if it is not integer (if it is string type) I get an error. Some people suggested (thanks to you all) using float but XAMPP returns a scientific notation this time.

Comment: I see. This hopefully satisfied an explanation as to why then. If its an issue with passing it of type string, it might be an issue passing it as type float too (depends on how they validate on their end).

Comment: Yes these are definitely the explanation of why, thanks to you all. I installed PHP7 version of XAMPP by the way hoping that it could work but no... Unfortunately XAMPP has only 32 bir version for windows and none of them works.. I think I will switch to WAMP although it does not support SSL